# operations by groups function within a function and options across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to do some similar operations across columns into a dataframe I use. Please see [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qwd0b0i1ScOZasAt8FwCmUiNe9nzD-ci/view?usp=sharing) to get the database [not large file], which is generated by `dput()`

I want over the `cols= c("debt_GDP", "Top10")` columns grouped by `group_by(year,country_name_iso3)` to do the following three operations:

1. `inter = na.interpolation(cols, option = "spline")`
2. `sm=fitted(smooth.spline(cols_intep))`
3. `rollmean=rollmean(cols_intep,10, fill = NA)`

Here is an example with a **single** column:

```
# interpolate missing values
df_us   <-subset(pkt, country_name_iso3=="USA")
df_us   <-droplevels(df_us)
df_us$debt_intep <-na.interpolation(df_us$debt_GDP, option = "spline")
df_us$top10_intep <-na.interpolation(df_us$Top10, option = "spline")

# smooth series with moving average 
df_us$debt_sm <- fitted(smooth.spline(df_us$debt_intep))
df_us$top10_sm <- fitted(smooth.spline(df_us$top10_intep))

# rolling mean 
df_us$debt_sm_rollmean<-rollmean(df_us$debt_sm,10, fill = NA)
df_us$top10_sm_rollmean<-rollmean(df_us$top10_sm,10, fill = NA)
```

I want to exactly the same for each of the `c("debt_GDP", "Top10")` columns grouped by `c(year,country_name_iso3)`

What is the most efficient code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(imputeTS)
library(zoo)
```

Using `mutate_at` three times:

```
read_delim('dput.df.txt', delim = ' ') %>% 
  group_by(country_name_iso3) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c('debt_GDP', 'Top10'), 
            .funs = list(inter = ~na_interpolation(., option = "spline"))) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c('debt_GDP_inter', 'Top10_inter'), 
            .funs = list(sm = ~fitted(smooth.spline(.)))) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c('debt_GDP_inter_sm', 'Top10_inter_sm'), 
            .funs = list(rollmean = ~rollmean(., 10, fill = NA)))
```

Or combine into a single function:

```
func <- function(x) {
  inter = na_interpolation(x, option = 'spline')
  sm = fitted(smooth.spline(inter))
  rollmean = rollmean(sm, 10, fill = NA)
}


read_delim('dput.df.txt', delim = ' ') %>% 
  group_by(country_name_iso3) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c('debt_GDP', 'Top10'), .funs = func)
```

Plotting the output

```
read_delim('dput.df.txt', delim = ' ') %>% 
  group_by(country_name_iso3) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c('debt_GDP', 'Top10'), .funs = func) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(year, debt_GDP, color=country))
```

[image]

Comment: Great. One minor mistake, though. You write `na_interpolation` instead of `na.interpolation`

Comment: Oh, I hope it's doing the same thing, whether it's `na_interpolation` or `na.interpolation`: https://rdrr.io/cran/imputeTS/man/na.interpolation.html I just saw that warning. It'd be something to quickly check to see if they're actually the same values.